# get date from string when months start from 0

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have been saving my dates in the format where jan is 0 and dec is 11 and then creating new moments with `moment([yearVal, monthVal, dateVal])`.  However there is now a time where I need to use a string to create a moment.  The problem is that I can't find a way to parse it in anyway where it thinks jan is month 0 rather than 1.

```
var currentDateText = "2015-0-25";
var newDate = moment(currentDateText, "YYYY-M-D").add(1, 'month');
```

The above code worked except for months where the previous month had 30 days and the current has 31.  Is there any way to parse a string of "2015-0-25" as 25 jan 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to parse a date in that way, because that it not how dates are normally written.

You can split the string into the components, and create a date from that:

```
var s = currentDateText.split('-');
var newDate = new Date(parseInt(s[0], 10), parseInt(s[1], 10), parseInt(s[2], 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in method and I don't think moment provides once also.

You can split the string and then use `Date` constructor to create the date object.

```
var currentDateText = "2015-0-25";
var arr = currentDateText.split('-');
var date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
var newDate = moment(date).add(1, 'month');
```